# Axios GET request MERN stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mern

I'm trying to fetch some data from my mongoDB.
I'm encountering some interesting errors and I can't seem to figure them out.
This is my frontend request to the backend.

```
getStockByTicker = () => { Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/stock`, {
      ticker: this.props.ticker,
    }).then((res) => {
      const stockData = res.data;
      console.log(stockData);
    });
  };
```

This is how the backend code looks like, although - it did not seem to even get that far.

```
router.get("/stock", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hey I'm in the back end , the ticker is: " + req.symbol);
  //error
  const query = { symbol: req.symbol };
  const stock = await Stock.findOne(query);
  res.json({
    name: stock.name,
    symbol: stock.symbol,
  });
});
```

This is how the DB looks like

```
_id: ObjectId("6016dfc14c9f733d7775c8ad")
symbol: "TSLA"
exchange: "NSDQ"
name: "Tesla Inc."
```

The error I'm getting:

```
xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:5000/stock 404 (Not Found)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Connection between router to the express app

```
const stocksRouter = require("./routes/stocks");
app.use("/stocks", stocksRouter);
```

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: You're making a GET request to a route you only set up `post` for.

Comment: I fixed it  , same error occurs

Comment: You haven't show how the router is connected to the express app.

Comment: Hi , I've added it! thanks @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> app.use("/stocks", stocksRouter);
> router.get("/stock"
> ```

Your route on the router is `/stock` and you mount the router on `/stocks` making your final path `/stocks/stock` but your client-side code is asking for just `/stock`.